# Appendix does not have a proper title when using \appendix

Tags: sectioning, chapters, appendices

When compiling the following, for the appendix title, I get the title of the last chapter. First, the preamble:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,fix-cm}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[left=1.50cm,
 right=1.50cm,
 top=1.95cm,
 bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
```

Then the main prayerbook file:

```
\input{preamble}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{toc}

\mainmatter
\include{chapter7}

\backmatter
\include{appendix7}
\end{document}
```

And now for a MWE of the chapters, and appenix7:

For Chapter 7:

```
\chapter{Mealtime Prayers}
\section*{Prayers before Breakfast}
All--holy Trinity: Have mercy on us. Lord: cleanse us from our sins.  Master: Pardon our transgressions. Holy One: Visit and heal our infirmities, for Thy Name's sake.\\

etc etc
```

And for Appendix 7:

```
\appendix{Apolytikia and Kontakia from the Menaion}
\section*{The Month of September}
```

Upon compiling, the Appendix does not look like an Appendix, i.e. essentially has no title (as a 'chapter' title header) but rather has the title: "Apolytikia and Kontakia from the Menaion" left-justified and in the same font size as the main text. Thanks for any help you all can provide.

Comment: `\appendix` isn't a sectioning command it just changes the behaviour of `\chapter`  so you want `\appendix` once then `\chapter` for each appendix

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried changing the main file by dropping the `\backmatter` command, then adding `\appendix` and then under that `\include{chapter14}` (now numbering the appendices consecutively after the chapters, but to no avail.

Comment: @MichaelDykes -- you want to keep the `\appendix` -- and (as david said) use `\chapter{...}` to introduce each appendix.  `\backmatter` should come *after* all appendices.  `\appendix` resets the chapter counter to start at 1, and (in most document classes, not sure about `scrbook`) redefines the visible "chapter number" to uppercase roman, so the first appendix will be "Appendix A".  "backmatter" chapters are usually things like bibliography and index, and aren't numbered.

Comment: look at my answer to the following [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124545/appendix-does-not-have-a-proper-title-when-using-appendix)

Answer (score 4):

`\appendix` isn't a sectioning command it just changes the behaviour of `\chapter` so you want `\appendix` once then `\chapter` for each appendix.

`\backmatter` should come after *all* appendices.  Different document classes have different ways of accomplishing it, but in essence, `\backmatter` causes the "chapter name" (Chapter or Appendix) and number to be omitted.